# How does instagram calculate a week?

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

I have a past date for a private message that was sent on a Friday, but I noticed that Instagram changes the value for the "weeks ago" on Tuesdays for this message.

So, I got the 16 digit timestamp via a direct URL from instagram's data on  https://instagram.com/api/v1/direct_share/inbox/ , then converted this timestamp to a human readable date, but the "weeks ago" value Instagram is showing does not make sense to me.

So, I'm confused how this "weeks ago" works, can someone explain?

Comment: Presumably: `( now() - then() ) / 7`

Comment: You can use `moment.js` to that for you if on Web Platform

Comment: Yeah, it is a web platform. I'll try the suggestions.